# How to track React Native fatal and non-fatal crashes with Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, react-native, try-catch, crashlytics

I want to know how can i catch my **React Native app crashes (in release mode)** and send it into **firebase crashlytics dashboard**

I am not found how can i catch **fatal** crashes.
But i have the code example which helps me catching the **non-fatal** crashes and sending it to the **Firebase Crashlytics** dashboard.

```
const sendReport = async (error,errorInfo) => {
    await Promise.all([
        crashlytics().setAttribute("Additional_Information", errorInfo),
    ]);
    crashlytics().log(errorInfo);
    crashlytics().recordError(error);
};

// At first i placed my code into TRY and CATCH block
try{
 //some code which has error
}catch (error) {
  sendReport(error,"information about place of crash")
}

//I have the example with Network requests
fetch(url)
    .catch((error) => {
       sendReport(error,url)
       // i am sending url for know from which url i am getting the error
    })
```

My questions are these

```
Need i use TRY{}CATCH(e){} block everywhere for tracking non-fatal crashes ???
How can i track Fatal crashes ?
How can i do the dashboard crashes human-readable ? for example
    For Android its gives me "index.android.bundle:502:784"
    For iOS its gives me "index.bundle:30378:18 line 30378"
    Thats why i am sending additional information with crash
    for knowing information about place of crash
```

Comment: Have you tried going through these instructions? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics

Comment: Exactly. I have done it. I don't understand your question.
Sorry.If you are understand it better please explain me

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics is supposed to do this for you. It catches fatal crashes that make your application crash and reports them (as long as reporting is enabled for that build). You don't have to do anything for catching fatal crashes, let's say Crashlytics has a "wrapper" around your app.

Comment: you should still call the Crashlytics function in each function which you want to be reported if it fails

Comment: @dontdownvoteme no, you don't have to call anything, if your goal is to have crashes reported. You can call Crashlytics functions if you want to add extra info (breadcrumbs/context) to your crashes. Or if you want to log an exception without crashing.

Comment: Thanks, didnt know that. Well eitherway Google Aanalytics has been declared unlawful in many EU countries so I decided to drop it. Instead I will store these crash reports in Firestore. I know it can cost me something but if the app functions as it should then there wont be that many reports sent to Firestore.

Comment: @showtime I believe Firebases Crashlytics has a free tier, that is pretty generous btw. Firestore is a different thing.